# Chat RSS feed should not be Inline

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, rss

The problem with having an inline RSS feed of questions on a low volume chat room is that you tend not to be able to easily find the interesting conversations, which is what will keep people coming back to the chat room.  A wall of questions is what people go to the main site for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree. The feeds were not set up by the DSP mods, but by mods of other sites when we were still in private beta. I've removed the Stack Exchange blog and podcast feeds (we already get a notification in the header for blogs). I've changed the recent questions feeds to "Ticker feeds", meaning

> New items from these feeds will be shown via a slide-down ticker overlay that periodically appears at the top of the room, and will not be persisted.

You should not be seeing feeds dropped in as chat messages anymore.